# Determine which way Bezier path is 'facing'

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I'm working on a script that will need to know which way a curve is facing, meaning if all the points on the curve share the same X value, it's facing the X direction. I have the script below that will correctly show the global space vector positions of each control point of the curve.

```py
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
curve = obj.data
spline = curve.splines[0]
# setup array for points to be written to
pathPoints = []
# Iterate through the control points in the spline and append them to the array
for i in range(0, len(spline.bezier_points)):
    pathPoints.append(obj.matrix_world @ spline.bezier_points[i].co)

# determine if path is facing X, Y, or Z
# TODO

# DEBUGGING
print(pathPoints)
```

[image]

Comment: `global = obj.matrix_world @ local`   (Use * for pre 2.8)

Comment: @batFINGER so I'd do something like `pathPoints.append(spline.bezier_points[i].co @ obj.matrix_world)` ?

Comment: @batFINGER I got `pathPoints.append(obj.matrix_world @ spline.bezier_points[i].co)` to work, but how do I determine what plane is the major plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that I got working to solve this problem:

```py
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
curve = obj.data
spline = curve.splines[0]
# setup array for points to be written to
xGlobalPathPoints = []
yGlobalPathPoints = []
zGlobalPathPoints = []
# Iterate through the control points in the spline and append them to the array
for i in range(0, len(spline.bezier_points)):
    if float("{:.3f}".format(float(obj.location.x)))+0 != 0:
        xGlobalPathPoint = obj.location.x * spline.bezier_points[i].co.x
    else:
        xGlobalPathPoint = spline.bezier_points[i].co.x
    xGlobalPathPoint = "{:.3f}".format(float(xGlobalPathPoint))
    xGlobalPathPoints.append(float(xGlobalPathPoint) + 0)
    if float("{:.3f}".format(float(obj.location.y)))+0 != 0:
        yGlobalPathPoint = obj.location.y * spline.bezier_points[i].co.y
    else:
        yGlobalPathPoint = spline.bezier_points[i].co.y
    yGlobalPathPoint = "{:.3f}".format(float(yGlobalPathPoint))
    yGlobalPathPoints.append(float(yGlobalPathPoint) + 0)
    if float("{:.3f}".format(float(obj.location.z)))+0 != 0:
        zGlobalPathPoint = obj.location.z * spline.bezier_points[i].co.z
    else:
        zGlobalPathPoint = spline.bezier_points[i].co.z
    zGlobalPathPoint = "{:.3f}".format(float(zGlobalPathPoint))
    zGlobalPathPoints.append(float(zGlobalPathPoint) + 0)
# determine if path is facing X, Y, or Z
if len(set(xGlobalPathPoints))==1:
    print("faces X")
if len(set(yGlobalPathPoints))==1:
    print("faces Y")
if len(set(zGlobalPathPoints))==1:
    print("faces Z")
```